# Quickest way to test it a postgres table has ANY data in it?

Tags: postgresql

I have a table that is empty most of the time. Occasionally large amounts of data will be dumped into it and will be need to be processed ASAP.

I have a process that continuously checks the table and processes any data it finds.

What's the quickest/most efficient way of testing for *any* data in the table?

The obvious solution is ....

```
SELECT count(*) FROM myTable;
```

But this can take a while (especially if it's got a few million rows in it). Another solution is

```
SELECT reltuples AS approximate_row_count FROM pg_class WHERE relname = 'myTable'
```

But this only gives an approximate value.

Is there a better/quicker solution. NOTE - I'm *not* looking for an exact row count, I'm looking for simple empty/not empty boolean result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an exists condition:

```
select exists (select * from the_table limit 1) as has_data
```

The `limit 1` isn't really necessary as the EXISTS operator will stop at the first row anyway